# UK Visitor Visa/what to write in employer's name if I work for the government

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I'm applying for a uk visitor visa from morocco,I work at the city's government office,what should I put in the information concerning my employer in my visa form?

Comment: What does it say on your employment contract and/or pay slip?

Comment: It's in french but it basically says: "We underline the president of the municipality, attest that (the person) carries out its function within this administration"

Comment: And then there is a signature at the bottom by the head of the administration,but technically he doesn't count as the employer

Comment: What entity actually is your employer, then?

Comment: Normally it's a government job so it means that I work for the government not for a person,but I do have a boss,should I put his name in?

Comment: No. we are asking you which government agency/entity/institution employs you? Eg xyz city council; abc dept of trade; (name of) municipality etc

Comment: I work for the municipality

Comment: What does it say on your payslip, and on the official letterhead?

Answer (score 2):

Enter the name of the municipality you work for. Eg Municipality of Agadir. Do not enter the name of an individual.